# Cannot open site with sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Scenario:

I am using SharePoint online where i have created multiple site collections and only one particular site collection is not being open using SharePoint designer while the rest can. I have enable running script in SharePoint admin center but still it doesn't work.

see the error below:

][image]

Comment: is it a modern site ? like modern team site or communication site ?

Comment: @GautamSheth yes its a modern site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, since its a Modern site, it will not open in SharePoint designer. This is by design.

Reference -

> When you design your solutions, consider these key areas related to
>   the NoScript setting:
>
> 1. Sandbox solutions are not supported.
> 2. Custom JavaScript cannot be enabled on the sites by using "classic" extensibility options (for
>      example, via user custom actions).
> 3. You cannot access sites using
>      SharePoint Designer.
> 4. Some web parts are not available for end users.
>
>    5.Ability to access or update site property bag entries.

Reference - [Customizing "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites)

If its a classic site, you need to ensure that you have enabled scripting at the tenant settings. You then either need to wait 24 hours or run the command mentioned below.

Once done, run the following PS command. You need SharePoint admin creds to run:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://yoursitecollection.sharepoint.com/sites/test -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Also, in your site collection, go to the `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx` and ensure that `Enable SharePoint Designer` option is set to true.

Comment: i am having the same problem with a classic site,is there a solution?

Comment: when i try to enable sharepoint designer am redirected to a page telling me i dont have access. I am using the global admin account here.

Comment: wont work on modern sites at all as i mentioned. For classic sites, you need to run the powershell commands first

Comment: @Gautem Sheth in that case for modern site how do we create workflow,if i assume it wont be possible from SharePoint designer anymore. Any other option apart Microsoft Flow.

Comment: yes AFAIK, flow would be the option :(

Answer (score 0):

If designer is not working for  Sharepoint online perform the following steps.


Go to Sharepoint Admin Center --> Settings --> classic settings page --> Custom Script

And enable the following

**Allow users to run custom script on personal sites**

**Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites**