# How can I use or add Html codes(WordPress) to SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a WordPress Site and want to add it's codes to my SharePoint Site.

Can somebody tell me, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you please add some more details?

Comment: I use SharePoint Online and have too a WordPress Website. I want to buile a Website in my SharePoint  just like my WordPress Website. How can I add the Html or Javascript Codes to my SharePoint Website?

Comment: I want to use the Codes that in WordPress used

Answer (score 0):

Create a Team site and make sure you use Classic Template.

Download and Install [SharePoint Designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491)

In the site settings, enable Custom JavaScript. Which will allow you to open it in a SharePoint Designer.

When your site opened in SharePoint Designer, open *master* directory there you can either create master page with your *HTML* and *CSS*.

Or

You can replace existing *HTML* and *CSS* with your one.

> There is much more activities you will need to do other than this.

You can also use modern template but there you will need SPFx.

***Update On modern sites in SPD***

Official doc is saying no, [Customizing "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites)

While plenty others are saying yes,

- [Acces to Modern sites using Sharepoint designer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-mso_o365b/acces-to-modern-sites-using-sharepoint-designer/28b71fae-a987-4b33-9da8-699631c80068)
- [Unable to open modern team site with SP designer, error “403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272486/unable-to-open-modern-team-site-with-sp-designer-error-403-forbidden403-forbid)
- [Sharepoint Designer access denied – Modern and Communication Sites](https://techwizard.cloud/2019/12/04/sharepoint-online-designer-access-denied-modern-and-communication-sites/)
- [Enable custom script on modern SharePoint sites to recover your favourite functionalities](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/)
- [Cannot open site with sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239102/cannot-open-site-with-sharepoint-designer/269170)

> Personally my answer is *No* but you can try this and if it worked
>   please let me know.

Steps,

1. Get [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588)
2. Connect to SharePoint Admin

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com
```

3. Set `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` to `false`

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Comment: Must i to create in SharePoint a team website or a communication website? because my WordPrees's Website is not for teamwork activity.

Comment: Thank's for your Help.

Comment: @user13474012 Check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: I have installed Sharepoint Designer but i get a message: The Server could not complete your requet. how can i to Fix this Problem?

Comment: I already mentioned about custom script, [Unable to edit sharepoint site in Designer - Error 403](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-edit-sharepoint-site-in-designer-error/84e37666-9ddc-4966-a9f9-0d0910cd514f)